# Differential backup software with DVD burning for Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, backup, data-recovery, windows-backup

Do you know of any tried and tested incremental/differential backup software system, to backup only newly added or modified HDD data to DVDs?

And preferably software which can easily restore all of these fragmented backups when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbse-features.html) from BrightSparks can incrementally backup data to CD/DVD.

- backup, mirror, or synchronization (two way)
- backup to CD/DVD/FTP etc

It has a neatly designed interface with a wizard to configure a backup profile initially. After this you can modify "easy" and "expert" profile settings in a categorised window. The help files are linked to the interface, so clicking Help on any screen shows you context-sensitive info.

It has some nice extra features though I've not worked with these myself.

- can keep multiple versions of a file
- can archive files with encryption

Answer (score 2):

[Acronis True Image Home](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) does everything you would want/need in a backup software.

Comment: Forget the rest, this is the best, hands down. Plunk down the cash. This one is worth every cent.

Comment: Acronis is good. I've been upgrading as they come out every year for the past 4-5 years now. But, when they decided not support Windows 7 in their 2009 version, I decided it was time for me to stop supporting them. I did find out that Windows 7 has a pretty good backup implementation itself (still not as good as Acronis) and am using that instead.

Comment: I'm gonna bet they come out with a free Windows 7 update for all owners of Home Edition 2009, just about the time Windows 7 releases. I'll be surprised if they don't.

Comment: They have already announced HE 2010, which is a 29.95 upgrade. The only thing I don't like about Acronis is that they are on the "Quicken Pseudo-Subscription" upgrade model.

Comment: I hadn't realized that HE2009 didn't support Win7, it worked just fine if you upgrade Vista underneath it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Genie Backup Manager Home](http://www.genie-soft.com/) for about two and a half years.  It will backup to DVD (among other targets), and restoring from fragmented backups isn't a problem (I've done it.)  I have it scheduled to backup any changed files to DVD-RW every night.  They also have a Pro version, and a new product that backs up as you work (Timeline).

Answer (score 1):

[Macrium Reflect Free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp) should tick all the boxes here, it backs up directly to DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Freeware [GFI Backup](http://www.gfi.com/backup-hm/backup-hm-features.htm) offers Incremental / Differential backups to CD/DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a backup software, but [git](http://git-scm.com) can do all of that.

Although it's now a version control system, it actually started as just a bunch of 'file-system' utilities that would provide a basis for a version control system to be built on top of it.

It can be used to make incremental backups and the data can synchronized over many places. (Though not ROM mediums)

It's highly reliable, too.

Comment: -1 Cannot directly burn to CD or DVD, as you have stated.

Answer (score -1):

[ShadowProtect](http://www.storagecraft.com/shadow_protect_desktop.php) is **extremely** fast and allows you to do HIR (Hardware Independent Recovery).

Compared to Acronis or Norton Ghost it is very fast and runs very well.

You can create partitions while restoring the backup and optionally set the MBR to be recovered.

I switched from Acronis since Acronis isn't as good now as it was with version 7/8 (Too slow now).

Comment: -1 Does not burn directly to CD or DVD... see the product details page. And its not created for data backups but rather for drive imaging.